# What size should my data set be used for classification experiment?

Tags: machine-learning, analytics, weka, data-mining

Working on something for, I need to compare some classification techniques (support vector machines, neural networks, decision trees, etc). My contact person at university told me to use the Kaggle data set https://www.kaggle.com/c/GiveMeSomeCredit/data.

The data set consist of a training set of 150,000 borrowers and a test set of 100,000 borrowers. For me, only the training set is useful, because the test set does not have the outcome of the borrowers.

My questions is, how many instances should I use, keeping in mind the computational effort of a large data set. In the papers which I've used for my literature study the size of the data sets vary from 500 to 2500 instances.

- How much instances would you use?

Comment: If I was in you, and that's what I've done for my machine learning course, I would simply try to apply the classification techniques on datasets of different sizes to see how computationally expensive it is in practice. Then you can decide which is the most appropriate upper limit for you

Comment: On a standard macbook Air, it took me 241 seconds to build a MultilayerPerceptron with a data set of 1700 examples. On my pc I"m trying logistic regression with 1000 instances but after 10 minutes it's still trying to build the model. When I tried with more examples it's crashed saying I didn't had enough heap size (max was 998mb). Is this normal that it goes so slow with 998mb heap size?

Comment: 1850 seconds to build the logistic regression model, with a training set of 1000 instances

Comment: I do not know about weka in particular, but to avoid this problem you could try to use Stochastic Gradient Descent for the logistic regression and svm. It is an iterative methods, so it should not require such a huge amount of heap, as far as I know

Comment: it's a comparative assessment of Neural network, svm, log reg, decision tree, k-NN, etc. So all methods have to be used to.

Answer (score -1):

split the data,
training on 90% and testing on the remaining 10%:

```
size = int(len(brown_tagged_sents) * 0.9)
size 4160
```